# How can I convert \74 and \76 to its string representation?

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
Kindle-Wirel\\74wbr\\76ess-Reading-Display-Globally/dp/B003FSUD\\74wbr\\76M4/ref\\75amb_link_353259562_2?pf_rd_m\\75ATVP\\74wbr\\76DKIKX0DER\\46pf_rd_s\\75center-10\\46pf_rd_r\\07511EY\\74wbr\\76KTN682A79T370AM3\\46pf_rd_t\\075201\\46pf_rd_p\\075127\\74wbr\\0760985982\\46pf_rd_i\\75B002Y27P3M#jjdkasdjskjsk\\74wbr\\76jj$jkdsajdks
```

I need to convert `\\74` to `<`, `\\76` to `>` and so on...

How can I do it?

Comment: What is that string exactly? I have a few guesses..

Comment: Nah, just to remove Orkut's link protection. The URL example I got from tinyurl which is pretty big.

Comment: In non-strict-mode JavaScript, `'\74'` is already a valid escape sequence for `<`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the numbers are octal, and they have only 2 characters, so...

```
var newtext = text.replace(/\\\\([0-7]{2})/gm,function(all,n){
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n,8));
});
```